# Cannot open source file "gtest/gtest.h"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, include, googletest

I am writing C++ code using VS Code on Windows. I am trying to learn how to use googletest by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp1ifh9TuFI&ab_channel=Rhymu%27sVideos).

This is my project directory:
[googletestpractice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYGBW.png)

This is my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(This googletestpractice)

project(${This} C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(googletest)

set(Headers
    googletestpractice.hpp
)
set(Sources
    googletestpractice.cpp
)

add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})

add_subdirectory(test)
```

This is my CMakeList.txt inside of test folder:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(This googletestpracticeTests)

set(Sources
    googletestpracticeTests.cpp
)

add_executable(${This} ${Sources})
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
    googletest
    gtest
    gtest_main
    googletestpractice
)

add_test(
    NAME ${This}
    COMMAND ${This}
)
```

These are my include paths:

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
${workspaceFolder}/googletest/googletest/include
```

I have added the `googletestpractice/googletest/googletest/include` directory to the system variable in path.

This is googletestpracticeTests.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(googletestpracticeTests, DemonstrateGTestMacros) {
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

I get the following error: "cannot open source file "gtest/gtest.h". How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set your vscode-cmake-tools [`configurationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)? Ex. `"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"`.

Comment: @user vscode-cmake-tools is set just like you descrbed

Comment: *I have added the `googletestpractice/googletest/googletest/include` directory to the system variable in path.* That directory does not contain executable binaries, adding it to `PATH` makes no sense.

Comment: Use `target_include_directories` in CMAKE.

Comment: `set(This` is overkill, `project` defins the variable `CURRENT_PROJECT` that can be used instead of `This`.

Comment: @273K I'd even (personally) recommend just writing the project name explicitly. If changeability is the concern, it's easy to do find and replace for this kind of thing, and it can (subjective!) be more readable.